# поле для ввода в консоли

Tags: php, windows, консоль

Возможно ли создать строку ввода в консоли через php?

Функция `readline()` выдает `fatal error`

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function readline() in D:\php compiler\index.php on line 3`

а так же как сделать нормальное отображение в консоли русского текста через php?

Comment: Надо читать [документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.readline.php), где сказано что эта функция не доступна в OS Windows. Смотрите первый комментарий в ссылке для использования аналога в этой OS.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, а теперь распишите это как ответ а не как комментарий)

Comment: Блин, всё никак не получается избавится от этой привычки - писать ответ в комментарии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо читать [документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.readline.php), где сказано что эта функция не доступна в OS Windows. Смотрите первый комментарий в ссылке для использования аналога в этой OS.